# using htaccess redirection brings some weirds behaviour

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I do use htaccess for redirecting 301 some page

but it does some weirds redirection.

To be sure if it was not on my code, I just put an empty file index.php

but I had the same results

when I call mywebsite.com/accueil.html it redirects to mywebsite.com/?p=accueil

it is not what I'm expected.

I also removed that 301 redirection, but it still redirect to this.

below is my htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

#Pages principale après index.php?p=ma-page
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ index.php?p=$1 [L]

#Page de visualisation des chantiers 
RewriteRule ^chantier/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ index.php?

p=chantier&id=$1&titre=$2 [L]

#Page de demande de devis
RewriteRule demande-devis/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ index.php?

p=demande-devis&type=$1&categorie=$2 [L]

#Le permis de construire
RewriteRule permis-de-construire/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ index.php?

dossier=permis-de-construire&fichier=$1&p=$2 [L]

#Maisons en bois page générale
RewriteRule maisons-en-bois/([^/]*)\.html$ index.php?p=maisons-en-

bois&module=$1 [L]

#Détail maisons en bois
RewriteRule maisons-en-bois/voir-detail/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]

*)\.html$ index.php?p=maisons-en-bois&module=voir-

detail&categorie=$1&id=$2&name=$3 [L]

#Maisons en bois par categories
RewriteRule maisons-en-bois/nos_modeles/([^/]*)\.html$ index.php?

p=maisons-en-bois&module=nos_modeles&categorie_home=$1 [L]

#Demande de devis sans categorie
RewriteRule demande-devis/([^/]*)\.html$ index.php?p=demande-

devis&type=$1 [L]

#Articles du blog à lire
RewriteRule lire-article/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ index.php?p=lire-

article&id=$1&titre=$2 [L]


#404
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html


#301
Redirect 301 /home.html /accueil.html
Redirect 301 /default.html /accueil.html
Redirect 301 /index.html /accueil.html
```

anykind pf help will be much appreciated.

Edit : following functions seems to be the problem

```
function www() {
    $protocol = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' || empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || is_null($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        if (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 4) !== 'www.') {

            header('Location: ' . $protocol . 'www.' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        if (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 4) !== 'www.') {

            header('Location: ' . $protocol . 'www.' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            exit;
        }
    }
}

function trail() {
    $url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if (substr($url, -1) == '/') {
        $url2 = rtrim($url, '/');
        header('location:' . $url2);
    }
}
```

Comment: The redirect will never happen because the first rule will perform a rewrite `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ index.php?p=$1 [L]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

matches `mywebsite.com/accueil.html` which get rewritten to `mywebsite.com/?p=accueil`. 
You can do something like this to work around this behavior:

```
Redirect 301 /home.html /accueil.html
Redirect 301 /default.html /accueil.html
Redirect 301 /index.html /accueil.html

# only rewrite if not accueil.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !accueil\.html
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I edited my htaccess, but when you go on http://www.sp-batiment.com/accueil.html it still redirect to the wrong pages

Comment: Did you add the `RewriteCond` as in the above example (untested)?

Comment: yes I did, I copy all your code `# only rewrite if not accueil.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !accueil\.html
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ index.php?p=$1 [L]`

Comment: Hold on, will try it locally.

Comment: If you are using a subdirectory I think you must use a path in your `Redirect` statement i.e `/path/folder/home.html /path/folder/accueil.html`, I tried the above locally and it is working just fine for me.

Comment: I do not use subdirectory. but I stil have the same behaviour, even when I remove my 301 from htaccess, I don't know where it can come from

Comment: That seems very strange, perhaps the redirect is cached? Try to empty your browsers cache.

Comment: I have 2 php function that seems to be the problem

Comment: I edit my main post, but I think i need to create a new topic. thanks for your help, it really helped me to see what's wrong.